# find us on facebook plugin not working

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using [Page plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin/) for "find us on facebook".I set my Facebook Page URL as my company facebook page url. And i get html code and script from facebook Page plugin itself.I put my script code just below the body tag as well as html code are placed. But after setting all this, whenever i reload the my html page,there is no "find us on facebook".How to fix this

Comment: is there i need to add any javascript files for use this facebook plugin.I already add jquery.min.js

Comment: Please add a minimal code snippet that contains a minimal version of the HTML & JavaScript combination that you have on your website to the question.